# How to do an order by not case sensitive

Tags: c#, mongodb, sql-order-by, norm

I'm starting to work with MongoDB and NoRM and I would like to do an orderBy that is not Ccase sensitive, is it possible?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible (read http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/1491cfb04ec706b3/c2050f57daea3836?lnk=gst&q=insensitive#c2050f57daea3836).

You can store the value twice, once in mixed casing and once in uppercase. You can index the column with uppercase values.